# String to double function returning infinity result in embedded compiler

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I'm trying to perform string to double conversion. In gnu c compiler I'm getting correct values. But if I use it in my embedded compiler (renesas CS+) it is giving undefined behavior like returning infinity result.

Here is my code:

```
    double str_to_double_func(char a[])
    {
    char str[30] = {'0'};   
    int loop ;
    double result;
    int len ;
    int pos,n;
    for(loop = 0;a[loop]!='\0';loop++)
    {
    str[loop] = a[loop];    
    }
    str[loop] = '\0';

        pos = 0;

      len = sizeof(str)-1;
       for (n = 0; n < len; n++)
       {
         if (str[n] == '.')
         {
           pos = len - n  - 1;
         }
         else
         {
           result = result * 10.0f + (str[n]-'0');
         }
       }
       while ( pos--)
       {
         result = result/10.0f;
       }
       return result;
     }
   void geo_app_main()
    {
    double d,i;

    d = str_to_double_func("12.345678");

    }
```

This same code I'm using in my CS+ compiler (renesas microcontroller) without printf statements. When i run this code in simulator it is returning infinite value (d = infinite value).

Now i changed my code

```
double str_to_double_func(char str[])
{
  double result = 0.0;
  int len = 0;
  int pos = 0, n;
while(str[len]!='\0'){
    len++;
}

  for (n = 0; n < len; n++)
  {
    if (str[n] == '.')
    {
      pos = len - n  - 1;
    }
    else
    {
      result = result * 10.0f + (str[n]-'0');
    }
  }

  while ( pos--)
  {
    result = result/1.0f;
  }
  return result;   

}

 Here the problem is getting 1.234567800000000E+001 instead of 12.345678 in my CS+(renesasa micro) compiler.i checked this code with cigwin compiler.There i'm getting correct output.
```

the simulator output is
result=result   1.234567800000000E+001  double(8)R6:REG, R7:REG

Comment: `printf("%lf\n",d);` --> `printf("%f\n",d);` is enough

Comment: `len = sizeof(str)-1;`...are you sure?

Comment: You don't initialise your values, e.g. `int result;` and then `result = result * ...`. Initialise `double result = 0.0;`.

Comment: i corrected my code,by using while loop Instaed of using "sizeof" and also initialised "result" variable with 0.0.  But now if i pass "12.34567" it is returning 1.23456.?@SouravGhosh

Comment: Dude, 1.234567800000000E+001 == 12.345678!!!!  Look here: [Exponential notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)

Answer (score 4):

You must initialise your `result`. When you define

```
double result;
```

it is not guaranteed to be zero. It can have any value and will probably be garbage. Especially if every subsequent operation relies on `result` having a valid value:

```
result = result * 10.0f + (str[n]-'0');
...
result = result/10.0f;
```

You should initialise your variable to

```
double result = 0.0;
```

A memory checker such as Valgrind can help you to find operations on uninitialised values.

There's also the issue Sourav Ghosh pointed out: `sizeof` does not give you then length of a string. You should use `strlen` from `<string.h>` for that. But in your case, you don't really need it, because you already determine the length when you copy the string in `loop`.

And, of, course, you should explicitly initialise `pos` to zero as well. Otherwise, strings without a decimal point may not be parsed correctly.

(Finally, copying the string doesn't buy you anything, but introduces the danger of overwriting the temporary buffer of 30 chars.)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to M Oehm's answer:

Your `str_to_double_func` is overly complicated. There is no need to copy the string before doing the conversion.

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

double str_to_double_func(char str[])
{
  double result = 0;
  int len = strlen(str);
  int pos = 0, n;

  for (n = 0; n < len; n++)
  {
    if (str[n] == '.')
    {
      pos = len - n  - 1;
    }
    else
    {
      result = result * 10.0f + (str[n]-'0');
    }
  }

  while ( pos--)
  {
    result = result/10.0f;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: @PNR are you sure there are no typos ? It works here.

Comment: Thanks.i corrected my code . Now i am passing "12.345678"  but it is returning 1.2345678.i tryied with atof and strtod functions also.Those functions are returning  1.2345678 instead of 12.345678.why?

Comment: How do you display `double`values ? `atof` and `strtod` are ok. The problem is certainly within your function that displays `double` values. Show this function. Probbaly you should ask another question related to this function.