# After converting string to double getting incorrect return value?

Tags: c, floating-point, embedded, double

I'm trying to convert a string to double.  After the conversion I'm getting an incorrect value.  For example, if I send "12.345678", after conversion to double the variable is holding the value 1.2345678. In Cygwin, this code is working fine. I'm trying to run this code in embedded CS+ (Renesas micro) compiler. There I'm not getting correct values.  Why?

This is my code:

```
double str_to_double_func(char str[])
{
  double result = 0.0;
  int len = 0;
  int pos = 0, n;
  while(str[len]!='\0'){
    len++;
  }

  for (n = 0; n < len; n++)
  {
    if (str[n] == '.')
    {
      pos = len - n  - 1;
    }
    else
    {
      result = result * 10.0f + (str[n]-'0');
    }
  }

  while ( pos--)
  {
    result = result/10.0f;
  }
  return result;   

}
```

Here the problem is getting 1.234567800000000E+001 instead of 12.345678 in my CS+ (Renesas micro) compiler.  I checked this code with Cygwin compiler. There I'm getting the correct output.

The variable this holding value

```
result 1.234567800000000E+001
```

Comment: Please let us know how [the answers to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447091/string-to-double-function-returning-infinity-result-in-embedded-compiler) did not help you?

Comment: In my previous question the variable is holding the infinite value.This is the modified code based on your valuable suggetions.But now my problem is "result" variable is holding  different value in my compiler.

Comment: Isn't 1.2345678E1 the same as 12.345678E0 or 12.345678?  So the problem is simply in the way the value is printed, not in the way the value is converted?

Comment: In the calling function code this "result" variable is assigned to another double variable and perforimg addtion with value 21.345678.The result is 22.5802458 instead of 33.691.

Comment: Do you repeatedly parse strings and then write back the answers to strings? That's wasteful and asking for trouble. Anayway, your parsing function does not recognise the exponential format, so you must ensure that the values are written without exponent, e.g. with the `%f` format.

Comment: Not that it is at all relevant to your question, but Renesas is a company name, not a microcontroller; they produce parts from several different architecture - if it matters at all, you should be specific.

Comment: Had your question been *"what does `E+001` mean?"* you might not have got down-votes.  As it is, you are asking why the result is incorrect when it is in fact exactly correct.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that you know that you get an incorrect value in a larger sense. To 17 digits, the correct value is 12.345677999999999; your function returns 12.345678000000001. (I ran it in Visual Studio.). You can't expect to get the correct answer using IEEE floating-point in your calculations (see my article http://www.exploringbinary.com/decimal-to-floating-point-needs-arbitrary-precision/ ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `E+001` suffix is exponential or [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) and means "x10<sup>1</sup>". 1.2345678 x 10<sup>1</sup> *is the same value* as 12.345678.  The problem is not the value in `result` but the means by which you are presenting or reading the result.

If this is a value displayed in the debugger, then that is simply the way the debugger presents such values and you don't have a problem.  If this is a value output as a string by your code, then it is the means of output rather then the code posted that is at issue.